# isIPv4LiteralAddress has false positive results?

Tags: java, ipv4

When I try to check whether a string is an IPv4 address or not, I found out that the function gives the following results.

144.122.1 --> true

144.122.1.a -->false

144.122.1.333 -->false

Any idea why the first one is true?

The function is: `sun.net.util.IPAddressUtil.isIPv4LiteralAddress`

Comment: Indeed. .Net parses 144.122.1 as 144.122.0.1 and 144.1 as 144.0.0.1. It would be good to know why. Btw, you don't mention which function is doing this.

Comment: The function name is in the caption: isIPv4LiteralAddress. Actually the package is sun.net.util.IPAddressUtil. Thank you, I added it to the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can see why they did it this way from the [source](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/net/util/IPAddressUtil.java.html) itself:

> When a three part address is specified, the last part is interpreted as a 16-bit quantity and placed in the right most two bytes of the network address. This makes the three part address format convenient for specifying Class B net- work addresses as 128.net.host.

So it looks like `144.122.1` equates to `144.122.0.1`.

The full set of comments regarding the number of parts of the textual IP address is extracted below:

> When only one part is given, the value is stored directly in the network address without any byte rearrangement.
>
> When a two part address is supplied, the last part is interpreted as a 24-bit quantity and placed in the right most three bytes of the network address. This makes the two part address format convenient for specifying Class A network addresses as net.host.
>
> When a three part address is specified, the last part is interpreted as a 16-bit quantity and placed in the right most two bytes of the network address. This makes the three part address format convenient for specifying Class B net- work addresses as 128.net.host.
>
> When four parts are specified, each is interpreted as a byte of data and assigned, from left to right, to the four bytes of an IPv4 address.

Answer (score 2):

Or use a regex as shown below if you want to check if IP addresses are of the format 0-255.0-255.0-255.0-255

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 *
 * @author ragavan
 */
public class MatchIPv4Address {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String range = "(([01][0-9][0-9])|(2([0-4][0-9]|5[0-5]))|([0-9]?[0-9]))";
        String pattern = range+"\\."+range+"\\."+range+"\\."+range;
        System.out.println(pattern);
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher m = p.matcher("144.229.1.99");
        System.out.println(m.matches());
    }

}
```

Comment: That `range` _still_ doesn't look quite right (though it's an improvement on the original): it seems to disallow 249 for example. Should it be something like `([0-9]{1,2})|(1[0-9]{2})|(2[0-4][0-9])|(25[0-5])`? Myself, I'd just use `[1-9][0-9]{0,2}` and check the upper range separately (but I follow the school of thought that regexes are useful but not necessary for _everything_).